# How to use WebWorker with ts-node? (without webpack)

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-worker, ts-node

Is there any way to use ts-node with WebWorkers **but** without using webpack?

When I do:

`const worker = new Worker('path-to/workerFile.ts', { // ... });`

I get:

`TypeError [ERR_WORKER_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION]: 
The worker script extension must be ".js" or ".mjs". Received ".ts" at new Worker (internal/worker.js:272:15)
// ....`

Any ideas?

Tomer

Comment: That's unfortunate; one would hope that web workers would accept any registered module extension.  You could try writing a JavaScript file that just `require`s your TypeScript file.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but when you `require` a typescript file from a js file you're getting runtime exceptions about typescript annotations, I guess that ts-node doesn't compile nested ts files or something.

Comment: Hm, maybe the worker isn't inheriting the require hooks from the main thread.  Does it work if you add `require("ts-node/register");` to the top of the JavaScript file?  (I would try it myself but my version of Node doesn't support workers.)

Comment: nope, tried it at as well :(

Comment: It seems like the only solution will be to create some sort of ts-node plugin (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/711#issuecomment-433104488)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make an function to make the magic, using eval property of WorkerOption parameter.

```js
const workerTs = (file: string, wkOpts: WorkerOptions) => {
    wkOpts.eval = true;
    if (!wkOpts.workerData) {
        wkOpts.workerData = {};
    }
    wkOpts.workerData.__filename = file;
    return new Worker(`
            const wk = require('worker_threads');
            require('ts-node').register();
            let file = wk.workerData.__filename;
            delete wk.workerData.__filename;
            require(file);
        `,
        wkOpts
    );
}
```

so you can create the thread like this:

```js
let wk = workerTs('./file.ts', {});
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: To be honest, this is no longer relevant to me, but cool very idea, hope it will help others.

Comment: If you get an error regarding the `WorkerOptions` make sure to import it correctly: `import { Worker, WorkerOptions } from 'worker_threads';`